# "env" parameter not applied in container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm just testing out Docker so this might be a pretty simple question but I cannot seem to find out why it's not doing what I expect.

I created a pretty simple `Dockerfile` for testing, just to build a simple image that installs some packages, clones a git repo and build its requirements:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV PYTHONEXEC=python3 \
    PIPEXEC=pip \
    VIRTUALENVEXEC=virtualenv \
    GITREPO=https://github.com/test/test.git \
    REPODIR=test

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-virtualenv \
    python-virtualenv \
    qt5-default \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    virt-viewer

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN git clone $GITREPO $REPODIR \
    && $VIRTUALENVEXEC -p $PYTHONEXEC venv \
    && . venv/bin/activate \
    && cd $REPODIR \
    && $PIPEXEC install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["sleep", "1000000"]
```

Then I build the image with:

```
docker build -t gitapp:latest .
```

This works so far. However, if I specify a `-e` parameter on the `docker container run` command, it seems not to replace it in the last `RUN` command.

So if I run `docker container run -d -e "REPODIR=blah" gitapp`, I expect it to be cloned in `/app/blah`, but it's still cloned in the `/app/test` directory.

When I run a `docker container exec -it -e "REPODIR=blah" <container-id> env` I get:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=2f6ba38341d6
TERM=xterm
REPODIR=blah
PYTHONEXEC=python3
PIPEXEC=pip
VIRTUALENVEXEC=virtualenv
GITREPO=https://github.com/test/test.git
HOME=/root
```

So it seems that the variable is indeed passed to the container. Then why it isn't passed to the last `RUN` command so it clones the repo in the right directory? Am I missing something basic here?

Comment: Hi, I had faced a similar issue, but this was with Kubernetes, but i think the same concept applies, I was using a ENV variable in the my code which was set in as part of one of the containers, however, if i was modifying the ENV variable again they were not getting reflected in the code but were see as part of the container, the same way you see it in the `docker exec`, i think you would need to build the image with the ENV variable you want for them to be applied

Comment: When you build your image the `RUN` step is executed, and when you run your container with `docker run` the `RUN` command is not reran again. That is how docker works, you build an image and then you run the container with this image.

Comment: So you mean that this is not possible to do at run time? The image has to be built with the end-time parameters forcibly? If this is like that I don't see the reason why the `-e` option exist on `docker container run`...

Comment: The `-e` option for `docker container run` is needed when you want to pass environment variables to container that should be started. For example you have an app that has properties file and you want to override those properties when you run the container.

Comment: I see, then maybe creating an `ENTRYPOINT` which is executed on each run could solve the issue, migrating the last `RUN` command to an `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: Typically when you create the image you should use the `RUN` command to install needed dependencies. When you want to change those dependencies, you usually create a new image with different dependencies and you give it a different tag. So then  you have 2 images with different dependencies installed. And you can run containers based on those 2 different images.

Comment: For a couple of reasons, it's probably better to `git clone` outside of the Dockerfile.  Also look at `ARG` for build-time configuration, which could be a way to build an image that embeds a specific version of the package.  (And set your `CMD` to actually run your application, and it's probably easier to not use a virtual environment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a `docker run` you are instructing a container to execute Dockerfile's `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` command. Dockerfile commands that are above entrypoint have been already executed during build and are not executing again at runtime.

That's exactly the reason your github repo is being cloned to the directory defined initially at the `Dockerfile` and not in the one passed at the run command with `-e` flag.

A workaround would be to alter your image's entrypoint. You may transfer this part

```
RUN git clone $GITREPO $REPODIR \
    && $VIRTUALENVEXEC -p $PYTHONEXEC venv \
    && . venv/bin/activate \
    && cd $REPODIR \
    && $PIPEXEC install -r requirements.txt
```

to a bash script(let's call it `my.script.sh`) file that will be executed as image's entrypoint. Copy this file during build process in a preferred location, ensuring it holds executable flag and edit your `Dockerfile`'s entrypoint accordingly:

`CMD ["/path_to_script/myscript.sh" ]`

**This however has the caveat** that the script will be executed each time the container is started in contrast with your current setup, possibly leading to delay depending on `myscript.sh` content.